# Magento Authorize.net CIM integration issue with completion of order

Tags: payment-gateway, authorize.net, ce-1.7.0.1

I am attempting to set up Authorize.net's CIM payment method to work within Magento Community Edition, version 1.7.0.1. Since it is handled quite differently than the DPM and AIM methods, I have built it into the existing Onepage Checkout using an iFrame. I then pass it all the needed information, it works perfectly and Authorize.net completes the transaction and returns to the site.

Here is where the issue lies. I am not sure how to complete the order, and pass the confirmation to the database. What page would I send Authorize.net to for the return? I tried using /checkout/onepage/savePayment but it results in the following error:

> "{"error":"The requested Payment Method is not
>   available.","message":"Invalid data."}"

Does anyone know how I might accomplish this?

Comment: You need to send savePayment() BEFORE you lead them away from the site, and once the Authorize.net transaction is completed, they should come back to checkout/onepage/success – Zak 4 hours ago

http://stackoverflow.com/users/1507691/zak

Answer (score 1):

Having been down this road a few times, either plan on spending dozens & dozens of hours hacking at this or fork over the money for an existing, well-reviewed extension with evidence of good support. [You can find a list over at MagentoConnect](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalogsearch/result/?q=authorize.net+cim&pl=0), or search online yourself.

There just simply is quite a bit to do to support tokenized transactions, and the time/money investment can be quite big.

Comment: Agreed. I've used the one from the 800lb [redacted] and have had much success.